# How do I Force Users to http only on Certain Pages ? (PHP)

Tags: php, http, https

In my case.. I want only demo.com/watch/MOVIE_NAME to be redirected to HTTP. Otherwise, all the pages will remain in https.

The reason for using HTTP on /watch page is--> My website contents are hosted on a non-ssl server. And we cant serve that on a secured page(https). That's why I needed to /watch page redirect to HTTP.

I tried to use this code..But it shows too many redirects.

```
<?php

if($_SERVER["HTTPS"] = "on")
{
  header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
  exit();
}

?>
```

Am I doing anything wrong..Is there a simple way to do this... Please, Let me know.
& Sorry for the questions, but my searches thus far here, I haven't revealed a working solution, and I'm afraid I don't know what the best practice is.

Comment: I would rather focus on: _"And we cant serve that on a secured page"_. Why is that? Regarding "too many redirects", it sounds like you have some http-to-https redirect in your web servers vhost or in some htaccess-file?

Comment: By "secured page" i mean this page contains https.

Comment: Yes I got that, but why can't you server some pages through https?

Comment: Here is my htaccess file  ......  RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

# works for fast cgi users
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Comment: Did you try `header("Location: http://" . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"],  true, 301);`

Comment: I can't server some pages through https because I have embedded video source from a non-ssl server.   @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I tried ..but same problem... This says "demo.com redirected you too many times."   @Chilarai

Comment: It seems like you somewhere, either in your code or in the web server config, you have something that redirects all non-https to https. So when you make a http-call, that kicks in and redirects the call to https. Then you're page runs your code that redirects it to http. Then the first code/rule kicks in and redirects to https again. Then it continues like that until the server throws a "too many redirects" error. It's basically a redirect loop. You need to dig deeper into your application/web server settings to find where that happens.

Comment: If you cannot serve files from a non-secure location, it would be much better to setup a [reverse proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41594531/how-to-deal-with-mixed-content-in-a-website-which-should-be-secured-as-https) on your server and fetch data through it, rather than trying to use mixed content.

Comment: @Risfat, first you need to be in https to be redirect to http. Else you will get the same error everytime

Comment: I also think so... Thanks for the information.. @MagnusEriksson

Comment: I already tried that....Btw thanks for showing interests. @Chilarai

Comment: How did you serve the HTTPS site? You need to have an HTTPS site for you to redirect users from there, right? How did you make that happen?

Comment: Do you use Cloudflare or do you have an SSL certificate setup on your web server?

Comment: Yes...I have self-signed ssl...but not using cloudflare. @KoalaYeung